# Pass nested object on intanciate class

Tags: rxjs, behaviorsubject

When I try to pass nested object on the new Class(), it returns empty class.

I think it's because I pass wrong arguments.

```
class myClass {
    public selected: {
        category: {
            code: string
        }
    } = {}
}

const initialState = {
    selected: {
        category: {
            code: ''
        }
    }
}

private bs: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(initialState)
```

That's work good, I get myClass with values.

But when I want to pass values after :

```
setCategory (myCategory) {
    let value = this.bs.getValue();
    let newValue = Object.assign({}, value, {
                    selected: {
                        category:{
                            code: myCategory
                        }
                    }
                });
     new myClass(newValue) // return { view: {}, selected: { category: { code: '' } } }
}
```

I get `{ view: {}, selected: { category: { code: '' } } }`

**UPDATE**

Live code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bjlhus?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Could you post a more complete code sample? This seems to be working fine. Also, I don't understand what BehaviorSubject has to do with this.

Comment: You can find the needed code here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bjlhus?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the constructor to your class to assign the input parameter to the `selected` property:

```
constructor(state) {
    this.selected = state.selected;
}
```

Here's the stackblitz with the fix: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hokh2a

Comment: Thank you ! :) now, I can sleep in peace.

Comment: Cool! I'm glad I could help :)